# counting null columns Mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am wanting to count the null columns or with a certain value

```
    $q = mysql_query("
        SELECT SUM(
            (`foto` = 'avatar_small.png') +
            (`email` IS NULL) + 
            (`cidade` IS NULL) + 
            (`estado` IS NULL) + 
            (`endereco` IS NULL) + 
            (`numero` IS NULL) + 
            (`cep` IS NULL) + 
            (`telefone` IS NULL)
        ) FROM `info_complementos` WHERE id_user = ".$_SESSION['usuario_cargo']) or die(mysql_error());

    $retorno = mysql_num_rows($q);  

    return $retorno[0];
```

the problem is that it shows the result

Comment: What do you mean by "it shows the result"? I suggest selecting `COUNT(*)` where your criteria is true (columns are `NULL`, etc). Then fetch the result instead of using `mysql_num_rows`.

Comment: It is useful to show the result, or part of it, and explain why how it differs from the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COUNT` function in mysql to count the rows returned. So you want to filter out the rows that you do not want in the `WHERE` clause. This will count all the rows that match ALL the conditions. You can change the `AND` to `OR` if you want to match rows that contain some NULL values.

```
<?php
$q = mysql_query("
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `info_complementos` 
WHERE 
      id_user = $_SESSION['usuario_cargo'] AND
      `foto` = 'avatar_small.png' AND
      `email` IS NULL AND
      `cidade` IS NULL) AND
      `estado` IS NULL) AND
      `endereco` IS NULL AND 
      `numero` IS NULL AND 
      `cep` IS NULL AND
      `telefone` IS NULL");

$result = mysql_fetch_array($q);
echo $result[0];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What are you trying to match? A row that has all those NULL columns or a row with just some NULL columns?